# While performing a wordcount using MapReduce, is it fine to do the splitting of the data into words within the map function?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have found extensive documentation and example where this is done, but I think if the splitting is done in the map() function, this would fail to leverage the power of distributed systems.

Am I correct in this analysis?

Comment: By splitting, do you mean tokenization of the line into words? If so why do you think _this would fail to leverage the power of distributed systems_?

Comment: That is indeed what I mean. My understanding is that since the entire data would be read in one map() call, everything in the text would be read serially. Hence no scope for parallelization.
It would make sense if what Chris Gerkin says below holds - that the entire text is actually pre-split in to multiple segments, which are  passed as a list to the map() function.

Answer (score 1):

The input files are split and distributed across the entire set of servers, allowing for parallel map execution.  You'd also want to exploit the partitioning of mapped output to achieve the sorting necessary to gather the counts for each word onto one server (partition).  In this way the actual counting of words is made parallel, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to the extent that in the [WordCount example](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v1.0) the `Mapper` has some work to do: For every line he has been provided he has to split it up into words and emit these as Key-Value-Pairs.

But you also have to notice that the first step for parallelisation has been done before the `Mapper` even started: The [`TextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html) (it's explicitely mentioned in the example) splits up input files into lines. These packages are distributed then to different `Mappers` - in parallel!

The `Mappers` implement the "business logic", i.e. split up these lines into words. To me that's fine. As an alternative you could implement your own [`FileInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) (or maybe extend the `TextInputFormat`), which not only splits the input line-by-line but also word-by-word. This would be valid also, but then the only thing your `Mapper` would have to do is, take the input value and emit it as output key together with the "1" as output value. Would you like the latter more?

***The answer is:** The `InputFormat` doesn't run in parallel as far as I remember. But the `Mappers` do. So to me it sounds better that many `Mappers` take care of the tokenisation instead of one single `InputFormat` class.*

[This Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#closer) describes the internals of Hadoop and MapReduce quite good. In the paragraph for the `InputSplits` they say:

> By processing a file in chunks, we allow several map tasks to operate on a single file in parallel. If the file is very large, this can improve performance significantly through parallelism.

I hope this was helpful :-)

Comment: I think I got what you mean. The thing is, I was going through the wordcount example [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Tutorial), where no explicit splitting is happening before calling the map function. Is there something specific to the RHadoop implementation that's at play here?  
(PS: Thanks anyway!)

Comment: I only had a short look on RHadoop now, but I'd think that it's yet another distribution of Apache's Hadoop - or at least an extension. Thus I'd argue that you would see the same standard behaviour as with Apache's Hadoop: If not specified explicitly, Hadoop will always use the TextInputFormat to produce the InputSplits.